# Dictionary becomes NoneType at the end of for loop

Tags: python

I'm writing a sample code for a function that will add a list of items to a dictionary. The problem is that at the end of the for loop, the backpack dictionary becomes a NoneType object. Why is that, and how do I stop my dictionary from becoming blank?

```
def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in addedItems:
        inventory.setdefault(i, 0)
        inventory[i] += 1

backpack = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
backpack = addToInventory(backpack, dragonLoot)

print(type(inv))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function modifies the `backpack` object in place, and then returns `None` (since it doesn't have an explicit return statement). So instead of assigning the result:

```
backpack = addToInventory(backpack, dragonLoot)
```

You should just call the function without assigning the result back. `backpack` will be changed in place:

```
addToInventory(backpack, dragonLoot)
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I see the error I made in trying to change the object.

Answer (score 0):

Don't write code which someone else has already written for you.  This performs the same operation:

```
import collections

backpack = collections.Counter({'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1})
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
backpack.update(dragonLoot)
```

See [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) for details.